# estilizando uma ul que servirá de select

Tags: jquery, css3

Estou estudando aqui, mais para aprender um pouco mesmo, e estou tentando desenvolver um `select option` com uma `ul` partindo do `select`.

A população da `ul` já está correta.

```js
$(".selectOption").on("click", function() {
  $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "visible");
}); 

$(".opcoes li").on("click", function() {
  $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");
}); 

$("#select > option").each(function() {
  $(".opcoes").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
    
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}

#select {
  display: none;
}

.selectOption:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}

.selectOption, .opcoes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.opcoes {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.opcoes li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  color: rgb(0,0,0); /* alterado para visualizar melhor */
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
  border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 1px solid;
}

.opcoes li:active {
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.opcoes li:hover + .selectOption:after {
  color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  background-image: url(_imgs/setaCima.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="1">um</option>
  <option value="2">dois</option>
  <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>

<div class="selectOption">
  <ul class="opcoes">
     <li id="">Escolha a opção abaixo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Meu objetivo agora é fazer com que ao `clicar` em uma `li`, a **ul** se retraia, isto é, volte a `overflow:hidden`.
Mas o que eu fiz não resolveu.

Outra dificuldade que estou tendo é a de colocar a figura de uma **seta** no **topo direito da ul** (**nova select**).

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O seu primeiro listener no `.selectOption` deve estar reexibindo as options sempre que você clica em alguma opção. Isto acontece porque os eventos se propagam para os elementos pais. Para impedir que isto aconteça, tente utilizar a função `event.stopPropagation()` e `event.preventDefault()` no listener que oculta as options:

```
// lembre de receber o argumento 'event'
$(".opcoes li").on("click", function(event) {
    $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Sobre a seta, é necessário utilizar a propriedade `content` quando utilizando `:after` ou `:before`:

```
.selectOption:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    ...
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Sobre o event.stopPropagation() não ocorreu nada após a retifica. Sobre o a seta, resolveu. Tentei evet.stop() também e nada.

Comment: Ou seja, quando eu clico em uma li ou retiro o foco da ul a ul não se retrai

Comment: Consegui fazendo um if   $(".selectOption").click( function() {
   if(contador % 2 == 0) $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "visible") ;
   else  $(".opcoes").css("overflow", "hidden");
   contador++;
  });

Comment: Agora preciso arranjar uma forma de ao clicar em uma li, ela passar a ser a primeira li

Comment: @CarlosRocha Já que você está utilizando jQuery, mover a li é fácil. Algo como `$(this).prepend($(this).parent())` no handler do `.opcoes li` deve bastar. Com isso, o elemento não é duplicado, apenas movido para o início da lista. Mas talvez seja melhor você exibir o item selecionado de outra forma, sem mover as lis, visto que com essa abordagem, seus elementos ficarão bagunçados.

Comment: Sobre o `event.stropPropagation();` não ter funcionado, tente adicionar `event.preventDefault();`.